# Gmail warning message when sending email from Laravel web app

Tags: php, laravel, gmail

I have created a web app in Laravel and uploaded on a live server. After a user fills a form, an email is send to my inbox and a feedback message is send to the client inbox having an **PDF attachment**. The client gets the feedback email but the problem is that Gmail displays a warning message concerning the attachment **Be careful with this message. It contains content that's typically used to steal personal information. Learn more
Report this suspicious message   Ignore, I trust this message** . My site has an SSL certificate. Cant seem to know what the problem is. Please assist?

Comment: pretty sure this is part of the google phishing filters. It's not an option that can be controlled. Only clicking on the links in the header banner informing that the message is safe will trigger the bypass response.

Comment: whats the encryption you use?

Comment: @Juakali92 Thats true,, I have tried that and it works, the problem is tht clients may not know about this and report my site as a phishing site (which coluld make my domain be blacklisted). I am looking for a solution to STOP this message instantly without reappearing

Comment: @AthulRaj Am using **tls** on **port 26** I have added it in **config/mail.php** in laravel app

Comment: you can use ssl encryption right?

Comment: @AthulRaj Tried ssl but the error persists

Comment: @Pweb contact their gmail support and get ahead of it. Not only will they provide of a solution but they may whitelist your domain.

Comment: @Juakali92 Just checked this website: http://www.bannedcheck.com/ and found my domain is not blacklisted. Kindly give me the link to Gmail support

Comment: @Pweb this is completely seperate to email filtering. Take a look at the contact center for more help. https://www.google.com/contact/

Comment: @Juakali92  Was trying to tweak my code and found that when I remove the code concerning the email attachment I get the email message without the error from Gmail. When I add the code the message reappears,, Was wondering if this could be an error with the PDF package I installed from this [link](https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf) ,Can a package be compromised to contain a hidden phishing scheme?

Comment: @Juakali92 I have also contacted Google support as you advised but am yet to receive any response..

Comment: @Pweb have a look at this forum post https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/5nJ7vGYZluE - it seems to be so random that there's no pattern, only what's detected by their filters. You've done the best thing just by contacting them. There's no real answer from outside google

Comment: @Juakali92 Thanks alot will check it out. Actually I found help from this link: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/. I had not configured DKIM and DMARC in my emails